# Difference between XPath & XQuery when selecting attribute value

Tags: xpath, xquery

There seems to be a difference in how XPath and XQuery selects attributes.
Here is a toy example stolen from W3Schools:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
    <book category="cooking">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
    <book category="children">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

I want to retrieve the values of the `lang` attributes.
So, naively I do:
`//title/@lang` which works perfectly ... on an XPath evaluator but **not** on an XQuery evaluator.

What I **need** to know: How should I write my XPath expression to work on an XQuery evaluator?

What I **want** to know: What is going on?!

Here's the TL part:

I'm on a legacy platform without these capabilities so I send the XML and my query expression to an external service, which I believe is a Saxon-based XQuery evaluator. My syntax works as expected on [CodeBeautify's XPath Tester](https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester).

I've also verified this difference on [xpathtester.com](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery): It works as expected in XPath mode but not in XQuery mode. (Note: link is not encrypted.).

xpathtester.com returns the following error message: `ERROR - Cannot create an attribute node (lang) whose parent is a document node`

Comment: Which error or result exactly do you get when it doesn't work with XQuery? Some message about not being able to serialize attribute nodes not being part of an element?

Comment: @Martin Honnen: xpathtester.com complains that "ERROR - Cannot create an attribute node (lang) whose parent is a document node" but our external service just returns no hits without complaining.

Comment: I think the result you get will very much depend on the XQuery tool and the API its uses, it is possible to select an attribute node in both XPath and XQuery but the usual result of an XQuery is some newly constructed and then serialized result and free standing attribute can't be serialized with the usual default of XML serialization. In XQuery 3.1, you could serialize them using the `adaptive` output method: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nzd8bR

Comment: XQuery by default will raise an error if it is incapable of producing a valid XML output. A sequence of attributes nodes isn't a valid XML output (XML attributes must be held by an element node, which is what your error message is complaining about). You can use `<ul>{for $l in //title/@lang return <li>{$l}</li>}</ul>` if you want to produce an XML that holds all the `lang` attributes of your input XML without using alternative output methods ([try it here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/2cdcb073e10acfa78c36137449be2098))

Comment: @Aaron: Thanks for the information that XQuery needs to return complete elements. I didn't know that. I don't really see the point of your snippet. Isn't the result the same as XPath `//title`?

Comment: I constructed the snippet around the `//title/@lang` you wanted to use. It returns a sequence of `lang` attributes.Those are attributes so you need to hold them onto elements, hence the `<li>` elements I create in the FLWR expression. I enclosed these elements into a `<ul>` element because I mistakenly remembered that XQuery had to output a single XML document (with a single XML root element that would be that `<ul>`), but XQuery has no problem outputting sequences of XML documents so it would have worked without it (or with `//title` which also returns multiple XML documents)

Answer (score 1):

The expression `//title/@lang` is valid under both XPath and XQuery, and returns a sequence of two attribute nodes.

Where you are seeing differences is in how different XPath and XQuery clients handle a result consisting of two attribute nodes.

If the tool tries to serialize the result as XML, it's going to fail, because XML serialization tries to construct a document node and attach the attributes to the document.

So you need to look at what options your XPath or XQuery tool provides for displaying the results.

Answer (score 1):

After really having understood what @Martin Honnen and @Aaron were talking about and some deep dives in tutorials, I think I've come up with a solution that I'm happy with:

`string-join((for $l in //title/@lang return string($l)) , ',')`

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nzd8bR/2

Comment: Nice one, note that you can simplify it into `string-join(//title/@lang, ',')` as `string-join` will cast the elements of its input into string automatically.